# Correct definition

Tags: expressions

Is there a definition for such school subjects as literature, biology, history and others in the English language? Can we call them “ oral subjects”?

Comment: On what criterion would you want to call them "oral subjects"? As opposed to what kind of other subjects? Can you elaborate? I think this is a potentially good question and needs to be clearer.

Comment: Literature is more often non-verbal than it is oral. (Although it could be described that way in context.) Also, I've never heard of biology described as *oral*. It's a strange subject to have included in the group.

Answer (score -1):

I've never heard them referred to as oral subjects, but I believe they are all included in "liberal arts".  https://www.britannica.com/topic/liberal-arts

Comment: Where does "oral" fit in this scheme of things, then?

Comment: How is biology considered to be a liberal art? It's a science.

Comment: Please note, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to avoid deletion - for example, adding a definition for *liberal arts*, linked to the source. You should also explain why you think biology falls within that definition. For further guidance, see [answer].  :-)